# Swift collection view delegate inside UIView class

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview

I have a collection view via storyboard that is inside a UIView. I'm subclassing UIView and calling a method called setupView(). When I try to assign the delegates and datasource from the class it doesn't appear to work. Can I assign the delegate and datasource via this class or does it have to be done via a controller?

Here is my code:

```
class homeView: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
let storedService = StoredService()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    print("I was called") // This doesn't print out!
    setupView() 
}

fileprivate func setupView() {

    collectionView.dataSource = storedService
    collectionView.delegate = storedService
}
```

Comment: "This doesn't print out!" because you use init(frame: CGRect) for an entity from the Storyboard. You must use initWithCoder:

Comment: use `drawRect` method , to setup your view or `awakeNib`

Comment: Thanks, drawRect solved it!

Comment: It doesn’t make sense to override drawRect if you will not draw anything. For this kind of of situations it’s better to override the init.

Answer (score -1):

Sure. It indeed can be done via the UIView class. but It will not work inside the `init(frame: CGRect)` method. You need to run it, inside the `layoutSubviews()` or the `draw(_ rect: CGRect)`

like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
}
```